# Implementing Drag And Drop on JTable to custom JComponent

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

The program for which I wanted to solve the problem first was to complex, so I decided to write a sample program just to solve this drag and drop problem.

So I have written a program with a JTable, filled with Integers from 0 to 100. In the second colum, theres simply column1*2 displayed. This table has DragEnabled.

On the same `JPanel` there's a `JTextArea` onto which the rows can be dragged.

If I now could implement the Drag and Drop mechanism by myself, I would understand the process well enough to implement it in my other application.

My problem is that I dont know where to start. I've read a lot in the web (on the official Java tutorials too) but I wasn't able to understand it. My questions include:

- Do I need to have a custom `TransferHandler` class?
- When do I implement the interfaces `DropTargetListener` and `TransferHandler`?

Which method do I have to override to "send" my data and which one to "receive" it?

---

edit

---

Hi Guys

Sorry that I did not post my code on first advance. Because it did not work I thaught that it's rubbish and would not be useful here.
But:

Heres my Code:

```
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Windows();

        }
    });
}

}

    import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class MyTable extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<TableData> data;

    public MyTable(){
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
            data.add(new TableData());
        }
    }

    public TableData getTableData(int index){
        return data.get(index);
    }


    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        if (arg1 == 0){
            return data.get(arg0).getValue();
        }
        return data.get(arg0).getDoubleValue();
    }





}

    import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler.TransferSupport;


public class MyTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

public MyTransferHandler(){
    super();
}

@Override
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c){
    return COPY;
}

@Override
public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c){
    return null; //I have absolutely no idea how I could get the selected Row out of the JTable???
}

@Override
public void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable t, int action){
}

public boolean canImport(TransferSupport t){
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean importData(TransferSupport t){
    return true;
}

}

    import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TableData implements Transferable{
        public static DataFlavor FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(TableData.class, "TableData"); 
        private static int history=0;
        private int value;
        private int doubleValue;

        public TableData(){
            value = history;
            doubleValue = history*2;
            history++;
        }

        public int getValue(){
            return value;
        }

        public int getDoubleValue(){
            return doubleValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor){
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{FLAVOR};
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return flavor.equals(FLAVOR);
        }
    }

    import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class Windows extends JFrame {

public Windows(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTable());
    table.setDragEnabled(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(textArea);



    this.add(panel);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: It's a good start to "write a sample program just to solve this drag and drop problem." It would be even better to post the code.

Comment: @WChargin Yeah sorry. I've noticed my fault and uploaded the source code. I'd be really happy if someone could help me understanding this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to solve the issue by myself.
Here is how I got it to work:

I implemented Transferable in TableData and wrote 2 TransferHandler.
One for exporting Data and one for importing Data.